# MongoDB: Querying for subdocuments: Java

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

Writing a mongoDB 'query and update' in Java.

The mongoDB Collection(Name: reduced) result(map-reduce result) looks like below:

*Value Field:*

```
{ "value" : 

    { 
        "User_Name" : "Mitchamoreagent",
        "tweets" : ["RT    Perspectives:
        Texas Insurer of Last Resort Charts Course Through Reform Law", "RT  Texas sale
        s tax-free weekend set for Aug. 19-21", "RT  The New Normal: Billion-Dollar", "R
        T  Austin Water is responding to a 12-inch water main leak at Burnet Rd. and And
        erson Lane in North Austin."] 
    }
}
```

Trying to find all the the User_Name's whose tweets contain a 'word' which I can specify using regex.

To achieve this I tried AggregationOutput which works fine with simple cases. But this structure, I am not able to get through it.

*Code:*

```
 DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",new BasicDBObject("value",new    BasicDBObject("tweets", new BasicDBObject("$regex",".*Texas.*"))));
 DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0); 
 DBObject nest = new BasicDBObject("value", new BasicDBObject("User_ID", 1));
 fields.put("value", 1);
 DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields );
 AggregationOutput output = tweets.aggregate( match, project);
```

Here 'Texas' is the word I am trying to find, and I expect the output `[Mitchamoreagent].`

But the output is always an exception noRowsReturned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct your `$match` stage operation as below:

```
 DBObject regex = new BasicDBObject("$regex","Texas");
 DBObject condition = new BasicDBObject("value.tweets",regex);
 DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",condition);
```

The corresponding mongodb query that would be generated as in your question would be:

```
{$match:{"value":{"tweets":{$regex:"Texas"}}}}
```

which actually should be formed as:

```
{$match:{"value.tweets":{$regex:"Texas"}}}
```

The project stage should be built as below:

When you need to project a nested field's value as a top level field, in this case `User_name`, you need to project it using aliases, in this case the alias being `user_name`.

```
 DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0); 
 fields.put("user_name", "$value.User_Name"); // project the user_name for each record.
```

Execute the pipeline:

```
 DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields );
 AggregationOutput output = tweets.aggregate( match, project);
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how should the 'project' should look like if I only want the "User_Name" from the result. Since I am using AggregationOutput output = tweets.aggregate( match, project);

Comment: Can you explain this "$value.User_Name" in the fields.put()

Comment: col.aggregate( match, project); The 'col' in the stmt, should it be the name of the entire collection? or should it be tweets since we are matching the word with the tweets. It still gives me a blank o/p although I can see the value thru the query, in mongoDB shell .

Comment: It was a typo. It should be tweets. It is the DBCollection variable reference.

Comment: It worked. Thank you much!! I used reduced.aggregate( match, project); which is the collection name for me, which I used in the question.